# argparse: accessing all files in a subdirectory

Tags: python, argparse

I am trying to write a python script with several text files inside a subdirectory, e.g.

```
python script.py --inputdir ~/subdirectory
```

which will execute each file inside this subdirectory. How can one use argparse to do this? Should you write a function to access and open each file?

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--inputdir", help="path to your subdirectory",
                    required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Now, what do I do with `args.inputdir`? How do I extract files?

Comment: Define "execute" -- do you mean "for each file, do ./file", do you want python to import each file into the interpreter session, or do have a need to call the executing process before (e.g. `./my_script.sh`; `python my_file.py`)?

Answer (score 0):

It's not a job of `argparse`.

Use [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) to iterate files recursively.

```
import os

for parent, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(args.inputdir):
    for fn in filenames:
        filepath = os.path.join(parent, fn)
        with open(filepath) as f:
            # Do something with `f`
```

Comment: @ShanZhengYang, Thank you for your feedback. I updated the answer accoridngly.

Answer (score 0):

> How can one use argparse to do this? Should you write a function to access and open each file?

That sounds likely since argparse shouldn't really need to know what to do with the commandline arguments -- just how to get them.  It probably looks something like:

```
def process_file(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as file_input:
        pass  # do something here . . .

def process_directory(directory_name):
    for filename in os.listdir(directory_name):
        process_file(os.path.join(directory_name, filename))

process_directory(args.inputdir)
```

Here I've assumed that your directory contains only files (not more directories).  If it does contain more directories, you'll want to filter those out (maybe using `os.path.isdir`).